# How request and response event are different from each other in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, response

I tried simple server in nodejs. I expected the output of a program as

**Server Console -**

- request recieved 0
- request recieved 1
- request recieved 2
- request recieved 3

**Client Expected Response**

- you have visited the site this many times - 0
- you have visited the site this many times - 1
- you have visited the site this many times - 2
- you have visited the site this many times - 3

**Client Actual Response**

- you have visited the site this many times - 1
- you have visited the site this many times - 3

I couldn't understand the behavior. and following is the code i ran

```
//dependencies
var http = require('http');

//variables
var counter = 0;

//callbacks and functions
var requestHandler = function( request , response ) {
        console.log('request recieved ' + counter++);
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end('you have visited the site this many times - '+counter);
    };


//objects
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);


//executions
server.listen('8080');
```

What could be the possible reason for this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigating, I tried following code on server

```
console.log(request.url)
```

and it outputs

```
/  
/favicon.ico
```

turns out browser sends two requests to server.

1. localhost:8080
2. /favicon.ico

this is increasing the request count to 2 whenever page is reloaded. Here the expected requests count is 1 but actual is 2